# Bokeh: Model `Slider' does not exist. This could be due to a widget or a custom model not being registered before first usage

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-visualization, bokeh

I am trying to execute the Gapminder example app using Bokeh:

https://github.com/georgetown-analytics/XBUS-506-01.Visual_Analytics/blob/master/bokeh/gapminder.ipynb

```
 # Add the slider
    code = """
        var year = slider.get('value'),
            sources = %s,
            new_source_data = sources[year].get('data');
        renderer_source.set('data', new_source_data);
        text_source.set('data', {'year': [String(year)]});
    """ % js_source_array

callback = CustomJS(args=sources, code=code)
slider = Slider(start=years[0], end=years[-1], value=1, step=1, title="Year", callback=callback)
callback.args["renderer_source"] = renderer_source
callback.args["slider"] = slider
callback.args["text_source"] = text_source
```

And I get an error while executing the code to save as HTML file:

```
output_file("six.html")
show(plot)
```

[image]